# a generalization of Montel's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The standard Montel's theorem states as below:

A family of meromorphic functions F varying omitting three distinct points a, b, c on complex sphere is normal.

The proof could be followed using Marthy's theorem and Zalcman's theorem, which you shall investigate through simply Google searching. Now, if we change the conditions of the Montel's theorem, saying the three distinct points a, b, c depend on the function f\in F, a_f, b_f, c_f and there exists a constant C>0 s.t. $$d(a_f, b_f)d(b_f, c_f)d(c_f, a_f)\ge C$$, then F is normal family.

I have no idea for giving a proof for this kind of Montel's theorem. But I guess there might be somewhere using Arzela-Ascoli to conduct a classical diagonizing argument. Anyway, could anyone give some inspiring idea to this problem?

Comment: the proof is in the AMM article of Zalcman A Heuristic Principle in Complex Function Theory linked here (using Marty's theorem and Robinson principle as formalized by Zalcman)  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319796

Comment: OK, thanks very much! I shall check the proof...I didn't learn the Robinson principle before so it might take me much time...anyway... thanks for answering!